# How to divide an ellipse to equal segments?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, graphics, geometry

This calculates vertex coordinates on ellipse:

```
function calculateEllipse(a, b, angle) 
{
    var alpha = angle * (Math.PI / 180) ;
    var sinalpha = Math.sin(alpha);
    var cosalpha = Math.cos(alpha);

    var X = a * cosalpha - b * sinalpha;
    var Y = a * cosalpha + b * sinalpha;
}
```

But how can I calculate the "angle" to get equal or roughly equal circumference segments?

Comment: To do that exactly, you'd have to solve elliptic integrals. Not nice.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference.

Comment: Is there any other way how to divide ellipse to equal segments then?

Comment: the last two lines (X&Y) wrong

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-bezier-curves/61796#61796.

Comment: As other people have said, the general problem is hard. If you could tell us more about the context though, there may be some shortcuts. What do you need to subdivide the ellipse's boundary into equal-length segments for?

Comment: @AndyJones for procedural modelling of ellipse, where all sites need to be roughly equal. Otherwise it doesn't look realistically enough. Program will take 3 parameters: width, height and number of sides, and it should then generate ellipse with this number of sides. Again these don't have to be absolutely equal, an approximation is acceptable as long as it is not easily visually recognizable.

Comment: @lhf Ok, let's say I'll use this for rough calculation of perimeter, how will it help me? mathsisfun.com/geometry/images/ellipse-perim-1.gif

Comment: Hi @Riko , wouldn't your formula be just var X = a * cosalpha, and Y = b *sinalpha ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So from what Jozi's said in the OP's comments, what's needed isn't how to subdivide an ellipse into equal segments (which would require a whole bunch of horrible integrals), it's to construct an ellipse from line segments of roughly equal length.

[There are a whole pile of ways to do that](https://web.archive.org/web/20130729120854/https://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/MATHALGO/Ellipses.HTM), but I think the best suited for the OP's purposes would be the concentric circle method, listed on the page as 'the draftman's method'. If you don't mind installing the Mathematica player, there's a neat lil' app [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DrawingAnEllipseUsingCirclesAndLines/) which illustrates it interactively.

The problem with those methods is that the segment lengths are only roughly equal at low eccentricities. If you're dealing in extreme eccentricities, things get a lot more complicated. The simplest solution I can think of is to linearly approximate the length of a line segment within each quadrant, and then solve for the positions of the endpoints in that quadrant exactly.

In detail: this is an ellipse quadrant with parameters `a = 5, b = 1`:
[image]

And this is a plot of the [length of the arc subtended by an infinitesimal change in the angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Derivation), at each angle:

[image]

The *x* axis is the angle, in radians, and the *y* axis is the length of the arc that would be subtended by a change in angle of 1 radian. The formula, which can be derived using the equations in the Wikipedia article I just linked, is `y = Sqrt(a^2 Sin^2(x) + b^2 Cos^2(x))`. The important thing to note though is that the integral of this function - the area under this curve - is the length of the arc in the whole quadrant.

Now, we can approximate it by a straight line:

[image]

which has gradient `m = (a-b) / (Pi/2)` and *y* intercept `c = b`. Using simple geometry, we can deduce that the area under the red curve is `A = (a+b)*Pi/4`.

Using this knowledge, and the knowledge that the area under the curve is the total length of the curve, the problem of constructing an approximation to the ellipse reduces to finding say a [midpoint-rule quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method) (other quadratures would work too, but this is the simplest) of the red line such that each rectangle has equal area.

Converting that sentence to an equation, and representing the position of a rectangle in a quadrature by it's left hand boundary `x` and its width `w`, we get that:

```
(v*m)*w^2 + (m*x+c)*w - A/k == 0
```

where `k` is the number of pieces we want to use to approximate the quadrant, and `v` is a weighting function I'll come to shortly. This can be used to construct the quadrature by first setting `x0 = 0` and solving for `w0`, which is then used to set `x1 = w0` and solve for `w1`. Then set `x2 = w1`, etc etc until you've got all `k` left-hand boundary points. The `k+1`th boundary point is obviously `Pi/2`.

The weighting function `v` effectively represents where the rectangle crosses the red line. A constant `v = 0.5` is equivalent to it crossing in the middle, and gets you this with 10 points:

[image]

but you can play around with it to see what better balances the points. Ideally it should stay in the range `[0, 1]` and the sum of the values you use should be `k/2`.

If you want an even better approximation without messing around with weighting functions, you could try least-squares fitting a line rather than just fitting it to the endpoints, or you could try fitting a cubic polynomial to the blue curve instead of a linear polynomial. It'll entail solving quartics but if you've a maths package on hand that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could do so

Comment: @Jozi just updated the approximation to have roughly equal scales. Realised the previous one was making the approximation look much worse than it actually was. Ratio of the length of the longest segment to the shortest is 1.33.

Comment: Out of interest, did you come up with a better way in the end?

Comment: Hello Andy, Just read your interesting post. Do you happen to have an excel or mathcad sheet with your calculation example? Somehow I had trouble reproducing your results. Thx.

Comment: The first link to the multiple solutions document is dead, best I could found was this: https://prog.lmu.edu.ng/colleges_CMS/document/books/GEC%20117%20Module%209-10%20%20Lecture%20Note%20(Repaired).pdf

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, so I suppose this has to be an answer ...

Here's a mathematically simple approach to forming a first order approximation. Pick one quadrant. You can generate the data for the other quadrants by reflection in the X and Y axis. Calculate (x,y) for the angle = 0 degrees, 1 degree, ... 90 degrees. Now you want the little lengths joining consecutive points. If (x_n, y_n) are the coordinates at angle = n, then Pythagoras tells us the distance D between points (x_n, y_n) and (x_n+1, y_n+1) is D = sqrt((x_n+1 - x_n)^2 + (y_n+1 - y_n)^2). Use this formula to produce a table of cumulative distances around the ellipse for angles from 0 degrees to 90 degrees. This is the inverse of the function you seek. Of course, you don't have to pick a stepsize of 1 degree; you could use any angle which exactly divides 90 degrees.

If you want to find the angle which corresponds to a perimeter step size of x, find the largest angle n in your table producing a partial perimeter less than or equal to x. The partial perimeter of angle n+1 will be larger than x. Use linear interpolation to find the fractional angle which corresponds to x.

All we are doing is approximating the ellipse with straight line segments and using them instead of the original curve; its a first order approximation. You could do somewhat better by using Simpson's rule or similar instead of linear interpolation.

Yes, you have to calculate the table in advance. But once you have the table, the calculations are easy. If you don't need too much accuracy, this is pretty simple both mathematically and coding-wise.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however it is not an efficient way to calculate positions for 90 degrees for purposes of procedural generation in computer graphics. Could you try to determine an equation for the angle? (even with rough approximation)

Comment: Obviously 90 angles of 1 degree each is just an example. That's probably far more points than you may need. Generating the table will be O(n) (where n is the number of points); doing the reverse lookup is O(log(n)). This is a straight linear (first order) approximation to the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind (the function you seek). A more efficient algorithm would use fewer points but use a second order approximation (eg Simpson's rule) rather than linear interpolation for the reverse lookup. If you can code a more computationally efficient algorithm, go for it.